# Is it possible to transfer amount from 1st account to 2nd when transfer function is invoked by 3rd account?

Tags: solidity

suppose here i have **three accounts** and they have some balances!!

i want to **transfer** balance of **1st account** into **2nd account** when **transfer** function is called by the **3rd account**!

*if this is possible then let me know!!*

*Thanks!!*

Comment: Amount is eth or erc20 token?

Comment: it looks like you don't know what you really need (based on question and comment of answers). is it ether transfer or token transfer? what types of accounts? it would be better to re-think the question and ask more specific

Comment: @Aquila !! In simple it is balance of account that to transfer!! I hope you got it! if not! then please let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

From Solidity side it is not possible.
The keywords call and transfer which are used to transfer ether function only takes 2 argument one is address and other is amount.

> address.transfer(uint256 amount);
>   send given amount of Wei to
>   Address, throws on failure, forwards 2300 gas stipend, not adjustable
>   [Trasfer function](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related)

You should check web3 library. You can try raw transactions to get this.

Comment: is any possibilty in other way except this one? @shubham

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accounts you can create 3 small and simple contracts and easily achieve what you want.

Comment: i need only 3 accounts instead of contract!! so is there any possibility? @Xawery

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer the question we need to understand your needs better.

Here is why:

> There are two types of accounts in Ethereum
>
> - Externally Owned Accounts
> - Contracts Accounts

The scenario which you've described is possible when:

**1st account** - Contract

**2nd account** - External or Contract

**3rd account** - External or Contract

Comment: **3rd account=>**  owner account , who deployed contract!!  ** 1st and 2nd account =>** account addresses passed in constructor of that contract!!@Aquila